# Are questions about how to setup a community considered off-topic?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about how to setup a community. It's not so much about managing or moderating a community, but rather about the best way to 'create' a community.

Are these kinds of questions considered off-topic?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, this is not off topic. Setup is part of the community building process.

However, the question needs to be focused on a specific aspect of setup so that it can be answered. A broad "How do I set up a community?" type question will be closed as to broad.